# JS - Understanding closure

Tags: javascript, function, web, reference, closures

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change the returned value of a function. In the following example the `getObjRef` function returns the result of an immediate called function, which is a reference to an object. Then after a second it changes the value of the object however the reference initially returned does not change.

Q: Can I make it work somehow?

```
function getObjRef() {
    var o = {val: 1};
    return(function (obj) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //trying to change the referance after 1 sec
            obj = {val: 10};
            console.log("obj ->", obj);
            console.log("o ->", o);
        }, 1000);
        return obj;
    })(o)
}

var objRef = getObjRef();
console.log("objRef initial value->", objRef);
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("objRef after 2 sec->", objRef)
}, 2000);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aJz26/) (check out the log)

Comment: You are trying to jump through unnecessary hoops there. In the statement `console.log("o ->", o);` you acknowledge that the innermost function has access to `o` so why go to the bother of having the intermediate, self-executing function just to trap a reference to `o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work, if you change this line

```
obj = {val: 10};
```

to this:

```
obj.val = 10;
```

**Explanation:**

When you run the [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) you return the object with `{ val: 1 }`. The closure caused by `setTimeout()` retains a pointer to that object.

However, when the callback executes, within the callback scope you replace the reference to the original object by a new reference to a new object. At that point you actually have two objects: the one in the outer scope (`{ val: 1 }`)  and the one in the callback scope (`{ val: 10 }`). So nothing seems to happen, when you log the object in outer scope later on.

To fix this, you have to maintain the reference to the outer scope's object and just change its value as done by the code above.

Comment: Is there a way I could replace the entire object? ... like from {val:1} to {newKey:"hi"}

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz AFAIK you can't. Basically because you can't get a list of all references to the first object, which you would need to change to the replacement object. You could, however, modify the old object to look like the new one: `delete obj.val; obj.newKey = 'hi';`.

Comment: Super, you are the king!

Answer (score 0):

This works now: http://jsfiddle.net/aJz26/1/

change `obj = {val: 10};` to `obj.val = 10;`

**Explanation:**
You have to change the value of the referenced object (to which the pointer points to) instead of assigning a new object to the local variable 'obj' what just sets the local variable to a new value (but you want to change the 'val' property of the original object).